# Select helper not showing value of selected option in search form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postback

In my Rails 3 app I use both checkboxes and, in one case, a select helper to submit a search form. I applied some jQuery to the form so if I click a checkbox, the form submits. Same with the select helper. If I click the checkbox, after the page renders the checkbox remains checked as an indicator of the parameters used to get the search result. The problem is that the select helper defaults to "Select" after the search form is submitted. It doesn't maintain the value of the params used to perform the search.

For example, say I have three options: "Select", "Arts", and "Vocational". If Select is the default in my form and I want to search by Arts, clicking "Arts" submits the form, refreshes the page, and the records matching "Arts" are rendered. However the select helper doesn't display "Arts". It defaults back to "Select" when the form is submitted.

I'm using Ransack to do the search, so here are the actions in my Controller where I'm performing the search:

```
def index
  @q = User.search(params[:q])
  @users = @q.result(:distinct => true)
end

def search
  index
  render :index
end
```

Here's my select helper:

```
<%= f.select :profile_subject_eq, options_for_select([['Select', ''], ['Arts'], ..., ['Vocational']], :selected => @q)  %>
```

**(As you can see I've tried to change the `:selected` to no avail.)**

Finally, here's the jQuery I'm using to submit the form:

```
$(function(){
    $('select').live('change',function() {
        $(this).closest('form#index').submit();
    });
});
```

**UPDATE:** Here is the HTML output of the select helper:

```
<fieldset>
  <select id="q_profile_subject_eq" name="q[profile_subject_eq]">
    <option value="nil">Select</option>
    <option value="Arts">Arts</option>
    ...
    <option value="Vocational">Vocational</option>
  </select>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem.  Did you ever figure it out?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
options_for_select([['Select', 'nil'], ['Arts'], ..., ['Vocational']], @q)
```

According to the [API doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_for_select) the second parameter is the selected item itself, not a hash like `:selected => ...`

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't do the trick. I'm updating my question with the HTML output from my helper. Seems like something is off there.

Answer (score 0):

If your set on using just select, then you can do it this way.

```
<%= f.select :profile_subject_eq, [["Arts"], ["Vocational"]], {:include_blank => 'Select', selected: params[:q] ? params[:q].try(:[], :profile_subject_eq) : ""} %>
```